# Dynamically Resize DIV by Dragging Nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, resize

http://jsbin.com/ovODORove/1/edit

I'm sure you've all seen those design applications where you drag a node and it resizes the element. Well last night, and today I decided to give it a try.

So today I wanted to try dynamically resizing a div, and I'm a bit confused.

I tried various ways, but none seem to work.

Logically I know that by using JQuery UI I can set my class .EE (for east east) to draggable to make it drag the element horizontally, but while the element is being dragged I want it to also set the width to where it's position is. I assume by binding the draggable event to the elements css width would work, but when I tried that it didn't work.

If anyone can help assist me with this it'd be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**:
Using JQuery UI's resizable handlers make this a real easy solution as you can see [here](http://jsbin.com/IRasuga/1/edit).
[ThreeDubMedia](http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag) also has a nice plugin that enables this functionality as well. As seen [here](http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag/demo/resize2).

Comment: Something you should know... `width()` and `height()` are supposed to have parameters, so `width(100)` would change the width to 100px...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played with it a bit, and I've got it working. This may be not *exactly* right for you, but I think it's a pretty good starting point. 
I've assigned the same `stop` callback for every handle, and that controls the resizing in any direction. Also you should give a parameter to `width()` and `height()`, like Man of Snow said.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QNDeE/1/).